# Is it possible to specifically compare two dates in batch?

Tags: date, batch-file, cmd, compare

I was wondering if it's possible to compare a specific date *(in the MM/DD/YY format)* to the current system date, and get the difference in minutes?

In my past questions, I've been able to grab the dates of processes and folders and create the conversion to minutes, but I'm stumped.

My project uses Batch/CMD and Powershell, so any of those formats would be more than acceptable.

Here's the code that I use for grabbing dates to minutes with processes:

```
if exist "C:\Windows\Prefetch\JAVAW*.*" (
    for /f "usebackq" %%A in (`
       powershell -NoP -C "[int]([datetime]::Now - (gci 'C:\Windows\Prefetch\JAVAW*.*' -Force).LastWriteTime).TotalMinutes"
    `) do set "AgeMinutes=%%A"
)
if exist "C:\Windows\Prefetch\JAVAW*.*" echo JAVAW.pf was modified %AgeMinutes% minutes ago.
if not exist "C:\Windows\Prefetch\JAVAW*.*" echo Error: file not found.
```

Is a comparison to the current date (and outputting it into minutes) possible?

Comment: Isn't this a basic understanding of time and math? 60 seconds in a minute. 60 minutes in an hour. Etc........

Comment: Right, but how can I take the two dates in the format above, and find the difference in minutes? I understand that 60 seconds are in a minute, etc.